# Matplotlib: plot multiple graphs using same figure, without them overlapping

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a class which I use to plot things then save them to a file. Here's a simplified version of it:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Test():
    def __init__(self, x, y, filename):

        fig = plt.figure(1)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

        ax.plot(x, y, 'D', color='red')

        ax.set_xbound(-5,5)
        ax.set_ybound(-5,5)

        plt.savefig('%s.png' % filename)


test1 = Test(1,2, 'test1')
test2 = Test(2,4, 'test2')
```

Here are the results:

test1
[image]

test2
[image]

The problem is that the test2 image also has the point from test1. The graphs are generated dynamically in a loop so I can't hardcode the figure number.

I could make a counter and pass it to the class constructor but I was wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this. I tried deleting the test1 object but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the figure's [clf](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html?highlight=clf#matplotlib.figure.Figure.clf) method to clear the figure after you're done with one.  Also, [pyplot.clf](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=clf#matplotlib.pyplot.clf) will clear the current figure.

Alternatively, if you just want a new figure then call [pyplot.figure](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=pyplot.figure#matplotlib.pyplot.figure) without an explicit `num` argument -- it will autoincrement, so you don't need to keep a counter.

Comment: That worked great. Thank you. I just needed a new figure so I left out the `num` argument. I didn't know I could do that until now.